# why companding is used?

Tags: pcm, companding

Which one is the best answer?

Companding is used []

```
a. to overcome quantizing noise in PCM
b. in PCM transmitters, to allow amplitude limiting in the receivers
c. to protect small signals in PCM for quantizing distortion. 
d. in PCM receivers, to overcome impulse noise.
```

I think c is the best answer. am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts about the other possible answers:

```
a. in general, it can mitigate quantization noise, but cannot completely overcome it
b. the limited range is over the whole channel, not only the receivers. 
d. impulse noise is not suppressed
```

Answer `c.` is apparently the closest match. 
Did you check the definition from the  [companding](/questions/tagged/companding) tag at SE.DSP? Could you propose some improvement?